# AZ REST Command Forbidden

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Service Principal does have `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` API permission but it can't PATCH using the AZ REST commands.

It can LIST/ GET using AZ REST command.

```
az rest --method PATCH --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{OBJECT_ID}" --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body  "{web:{redirectUris:['https://URL']}}"
```

Error:

```
Forbidden(
{
    "error": {
        "code":"Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date":"2022-10-13T06:10:41",
            "request-id":"...",
            "client-request-id":"...."
        }
    }
})
```

Any idea why it says forbidden?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error you mentioned it seems to be delegated permission issue by the admin has to give permission to do that operation. Please check the same on Azure portal in API permission under App Registration

Answer (score 0):

**I tried reproduce in my environment got below results:**

I have an  Application with name **`testvenkat`** and added " **`Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`**" api permission and also **`granted admin consent`** permission which is shown below:

[image]

Now I tried the same commands:

```
az rest --method PATCH --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/'<Object ID>' --body "{'web':{'redirectUris':['https://< url >']}}" --headers Content-Type=application/json
```

**Console:**
[image]

I used the **`GET`**  method  to see my  **`Web-redirectUrl`** to make sure whether it is updated or not.

```
az rest --method GET --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<Object-ID>'
```

**Console:**
[image]

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

> ```
>     "error": {
>         "code":"Authorization_RequestDenied",
>         "message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
>         "innerError": {
>             "date":"2022-10-13T06:10:41",
>             "request-id":"...",
>             "client-request-id":"...."
>         }
>     } })
> ```

Please check the points

1. Make sure you are logged in correct az login < username > and < password > or az login serviceprincipal < application id > and secrets.
2. Check whether it has proper role assignments and permission role "**`owner`**" .
3. Also check the api  permission **`"Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy"`** has application type in microsoft graph api.

**Reference**:
[Microsoft Graph permissions reference - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-4)